# Adding an extra item to the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
trait,beta,se,p,analysis,signif
trait1,0.078,0.01,9.00E-13,group1,1
trait2,0.076,0.01,1.70E-11,group1,1
trait3,-0.032,0.01,0.004,group1,0
trait4,0.026,0.01,0.024,group1,0
trait5,0.023,0.01,0.037,group1,0
trait1,0.042,0.01,4.50E-04,group2,1
trait2,0.04,0.01,0.002,group2,1
trait3,0.03,0.01,0.025,group2,0
trait4,0.025,0.01,0.078,group2,0
trait5,0.015,0.01,0.294,group2,0
trait1,0.02,0.01,0.078,group3,0
trait2,0.03,0.01,0.078,group3,0
trait3,0.043,0.01,1.90E-04,group3,0
trait4,0.043,0.01,2.40E-04,group3,1
trait5,0.029,0.01,0.013,group3,0
```

And make a plot with the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(GEE, aes(y=beta, x=reorder(trait, beta), group=analysis)) + 
  geom_point(data = GEE[GEE$signif == 1, ],
             color="red",
             shape = "*", 
             size=12, 
             show.legend = F) +
  geom_point(aes(color=analysis)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=beta-2*se, ymax=beta+2*se,color=analysis), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.2)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_blank()) +
  coord_flip()
```

Which gives me the following plot:

[image]

I would like to add an extra element to the legend, namely the red asterisk, and I want it to say "significant". How do I go about doing that?

PS. If you like this piece of code, I have another problem with it, specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839794/reorder-does-not-work-after-adding-second-geom-points) :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add dummy `aes()` to `geom_point` - for example fill that is named significant `aes(fill = "Significant")`.

```
# Using OPs data
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(GEE, aes(y=beta, x=reorder(trait, beta), group=analysis)) + 
  geom_point(data = GEE[GEE$signif == 1, ],
             color="red",
             shape = "*", 
             size=12,
             aes(fill = "Significant")) +
  geom_point(aes(color=analysis)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=beta-2*se, ymax=beta+2*se,color=analysis), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.2)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_blank()) +
  coord_flip() +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 1), 
         fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5))) +
  theme(legend.margin = margin(-0.5,0,0,0, unit="cm"))
```

PS: I also removed `show.legend = F` from asterik `geom_point`

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you! Is it possible to align the the asterisk and the word "significant" under the existing legend?

Comment: @Abdel Done :-) I added `order`; `override` to align; `legend.margin` to decrease space

Comment: If I increase the size of the asterisk in the legend, it doesn't align anymore; the larger I make it, the more it shifts to the right. Any ideas on how to increase its size and keep it aligned?

Comment: Do you mean in "guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 1), fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5))) +" ? That is what I did, I changed it to: "guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 1), fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 12))) +", which is when he shifts the asterisk in the legend to the right.

Comment: @Abdel can you add `override.aes = list(size = 12)` to colour too? I think this is the only way

Comment: Yes that works, except that he made the other legend items much larger now too. Only the asterisk should have size 12...

Comment: Sorry, but for now I don't know any other solution, this could be another good SO question :-)