# Add significance asterisk to line graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data which I have graphed in a double line graph. I want to add an asterisk whenever significance is "y."

```
structure(list(Year = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3), school_type = c("Management Change", 
"Management Change", "Management Change", "Management Change", 
"Full Closure", "Full Closure", "Full Closure", "Full Closure"
), pct_change = c(3.7, 2, 0.8, -1.1, 9.2, 6.9, 5.4, 6.6), significance = c("y", 
"n", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I used the following code to create asterisks (after consulting [R ggplot2: add significance level to line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48578236/r-ggplot2-add-significance-level-to-line-plot)), but the problem is that I can't move those asterisks up to get them out of the point of the points, or change the font to be what I want. I tried nudge_y but it didn't work.

```
ggplot(fig4, aes(x=Year, y=pct_change, color=school_type, group=school_type)) +
  geom_line(size=1) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  theme_bw(base_family = "Georgia") +
  geom_point(data = fig4[fig4$significance == "y", ], shape = "*", size=4.233, color="black")
```

[image]

Whenever I want to add significance asterisks to a bar graph, it's easy. I put in:

```
ggplot(df, aes(label = ifelse(significance == "y", "*",""))
```

However, this doesn't work at all for line graphs for some reason. Why not?

Comment: Please make your question reproducible by including your data as a data.frame object e.g. fig4 <- data.frame(year = c(0, etc), ...your data...) or use dput(fig4)

Comment: Sorry about that, I have done so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Positioning of significance asterisk

The simple way to get the significance asterisks above the line or points of your main data is by adjusting the y value in the aes call. See answer.

You could pre-process this in your dataset before generating the plot by creating another variable for example sig_y with mutate if you are using `dplyr`

2) Typeface or font family: Georgia.

This is a bit more involved and I found these links helpful: [Changing fonts in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522732/changing-fonts-in-ggplot2) and this one: https://github.com/wch/extrafont

Making additional typefaces accessible to R:

```
library(extrafont) # package for accessing fonts on your computer assuming you are running windows
font_import() # imports all the fonts on your computer; may take several minutes
fonts <- fonttable() # tabulates the extracted fonts allows you to check what fonts you have and you can confirm that Georgia is in the mix
```

Packages

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(extrafont)
```

Data
(By the way, this is a useful way to provide data for any future questions as it makes it easy for members of the SO community to reproduce your question.)

```
fig4 <- tibble(Year = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3),
               school_type = c("Management Change", "Management Change", "Management Change", "Management Change", 
                               "Full Closure", "Full Closure", "Full Closure", "Full Closure"), 
               pct_change = c(3.7, 2, 0.8, -1.1, 9.2, 6.9, 5.4, 6.6), 
               significance = c("y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y"))
```

Script for plot

```
loadfonts(device = "win") # to give access to non-ggplot fonts

ggplot(fig4, aes(x=Year, y=pct_change, color=school_type, group=school_type)) +
  geom_line(size=1) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  theme_bw(base_family = "Georgia")+
  geom_point(data = fig4[fig4$significance == "y", ], aes(Year, pct_change + 0.25), shape = "*", size=4.233, color="black")
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I may offer an adaptation of the solution provided by Peter that lets you add text other than one *:

Here we again generate the dataframe:

```
fig4 <- tibble(Year = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3),
school_type = c("Management Change", "Management Change", "Management Change", "Management Change",
"Full Closure", "Full Closure", "Full Closure", "Full Closure"),
pct_change = c(3.7, 2, 0.8, -1.1, 9.2, 6.9, 5.4, 6.6),
significance = c("y", "n", "n", "n", "y", "y", "y", "y"))
```

And the plotting code:

```
ggplot(fig4, aes(x=Year, y=pct_change, color=school_type, group=school_type)) +
geom_line(size=1) +
geom_point(size=3) +
theme_bw(base_family = "Georgia")
```

instead of using  geom_point() you can use geom_text() like so:

```
ggplot(fig4, aes(x=Year, y=pct_change, color=school_type, group=school_type)) +
geom_line(size=1) +
geom_point(size=3) +
theme_bw(base_family = "Georgia")+
geom_point(data = fig4[fig4$significance == "y", ], aes(Year, pct_change + 0.25, label="*"))
```

At label= you can provide any string you would like to have above the dots, if that by "n.s." or multiple **.